# load a class from a given path

Tags: java, classloader

I have this simple piece of code to load a class from a given path:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    String str ="/Users/path/to/myclass.class";
    Class<?> cl = ThisTest.class.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(str);
}
```

Could anyone tell me what is wrong here? I keep getting `ClassNotFoundException` when executing `main`

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change `String str ="/Users/path/to/myclass.class";` to `String str ="myclass";`
According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String) this string should not be path to class, but class full name (like "java.lang.String").

Comment: How does it know where the class is then? (As in physically where in memory?)

Comment: Java have general order for lookup classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/findingclasses.html . User can add custom finding paths via CLASSPATH (like `java -cp /myclasses Main`)